# What is the usage for SynchronizationAttribute.IsReEntrant

Tags: c#, multithreading

there,

does anyone know what is the usage for SynchronizationAttribute.IsReEntrant? The MSDN doc is not clear.

Comment: When something is reentrant, it means that it can be called concurrently from the same thread -- ie Foo() calls Bar() calls Foo() -- and still work. Perhaps it does something to allow that. I'll be interested to hear if anyone knows the definite answer!

Answer (score 0):

if one service instance handles multiple requests this property decides if a queue is used to ensure thread safety for this instance. if set to true no queue is used and you have to handle multiple concurrent request and synchronize access to shared resources accordingly.